# Git Gui: How to exclude unnecessary files from rescan

Tags: git, version-control, msysgit

How to avoid scanning unnecessary/temporary files in Git GUI? e.g obj, pdb files etc...?

Comment: Haven't got that installed on this box, but have you tried .gitignore file? Git should ignore anything listed in that file by default so would imagine it applies here as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual mechanism applies, i.e.:

- list directories, files or patterns in '.git/info/exclude' - this would be per repository
- same thing but in a `.gitignore` file inside the repository itself - this could be committed and be per project, shared by all participants

Comment: Its worth to mention, that `.git/info/exclude` refers to the _local_ repository in contrast to `.gitignore`, that is shared with with everyone, who fetch the repository (I find the "per repository" just a little bit misleading). Additional you can define a user- (`git config --global core.excludesfile filename`) and system-wide (`git config --system core.excludesfiles filename`) file.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant with "per repository" and "per project", but thanks for adding the "per user" and "per system" ones.

Comment: Yes - but how to do these in the Gui?

Comment: YES!  How do you create the gitignore file in the GUI?  Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can tell, you don't create them in the GUI.  It's easy enough to do with notepad however - just save .gitignore at the base folder of your repository.